# Newline in input filed?

Tags: php

I am new to php and never used php. I have one application backend with php. There function for add new text. Its input filed. when I type some text there and if I need some text in new line than its not possible. If I press Enter key for add new line, its saving my data. 
my code for it like below.

```
public function create() {

    $this->set_form_validation_rules();
    $data["authors"] = $this->quotes->get_authors();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->view("back/create", $data);
    } else {            
        $this->quotes->create();
        $this->redirect_overview(lang("noti_success_added"));
    }
}
```

Please help me for solve issue...
Thanks

Comment: you don't have two activities. What you have is one activity and one fragment.

Comment: Search about interface  , how to use

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling your second activity is actually a Fragment (it extends Fragment). Therefore you have to have some Activity encapsuling this fragment. There are a few cases you may have in your app:

- Your Fragment is contained in your Main Activity. Then you can just define a method in the Fragment you can call from the Activity (via the findFragment method of the FragmentManager of your MainActivity). In that method you perform your task.
- Your Fragment is contained in a different Activity (lets call it A2). Then this activity will not be in the foreground while your MainActivity is in foreground (because only one Activity can be in the foreground). If A2 is not running in the Background (what normally should be the case), the onCreateView in the Fragment will be called when A2 is opened and your task will be performed anyway as it is in the onCreateView as far as i can see.
- If your A2 is already running in background while you are in your MainActivity, you can perform the task of refreshing in the onResume() Callback of A2 and call the Method in the Fragment as in point 1. If this is not intended (means sometimes you don't want to refresh your activity A2) then it get's difficult, but i can't see a case where you would want to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Try making the method you want to call **public** and **static**

You can use this option and just share the method among all your activity classes.

**ActivityA**

```
public  Activity_A extends Activity{
         ClassWithMethod.methodToCall();
   }
```

**ClassWithMethod**

```
public  ClassWithMethod{
         public static method methodToCall(){...}
   }
```

**ActivityB**

```
public  Activity_B extends Activity{
         ClassWithMethod.methodToCall();
   }
```

Comment: Hi ! Can you please explain little more, because I am student and learning...not know how can I do it.

Comment: But a static method would not be able to access non-static members of the Fragment (his second Activity actually is a Fragment) like the class MyTask.
So you would have to go with the singleton Pattern to access the instance of the Fragment which is not recommended and pretty ugly according to android design guidelines.

Comment: And What if there one more activity which have same function and need call in main Activity ? Like Activity A need use Activity B and Activity C

Comment: In Android only one Activity can be in the foreground. So when Activity A is running, Activity B and C should not be running. Therefore why would you want to access them. Are you sure you are not messing up Activities and Fragments?

Comment: Actually one Fragment activity and one other activity have function for fetch data from server. I want merge that two function in calling Main Activity with refresh button.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made an edit to the answer and i think the best method is to share a class containing the methodToShare among all your activities

Comment: If you want to fetch the server data on the click on the refresh button and then use it later in the other Activities you have to somehow cache it. There are multiple possibilities. SyncAdapter, Service, Loaders... It depends on the data you need to cache and stuff like that. Did you check the google training guides? http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html